# Would a "Classless society" be better than the present society?

Tags: society, marxism

In today's era many countries have 'Marxist' political parties, and their purpose is a "classless society".

Can a classless society be possible, can it run successfully run?

Comment: Can you expand your question? What is “classless “? When would such a society be “successful “?

Comment: As Karl Marx's "dialectical materialism" says that the present "capitalist society" will sometime change into a "classless society" where there wouldn't be any economic gap among people and no one will be rich and poor. Now many "political parties" are working on this.

Comment: Many arguments already are given by Marx, Engels and others. Many counterarguments are given by their critics. The variety of literature is wide and as the question is posed, it's asking for opinions. I suggesy you to ask for literature on the topic.

Comment: It's all about education.
Marx believed that the proletariat would have to become more educated to service their role, as technology advances.
An educated proletariat would be much harder to oppress.. In fact we're seeing that now. 
The tyrants are trying to dumb us down, but in the long run, it just won't work.
There'll be more tyrants, more war, more suffering.. but eventually, the educated masses will find a way to cure societal injustice in a way which doesn't seem totalitarian.

Comment: But if everyone becomes highly educated then who will agree to do labor-class work?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu we'll have better educated menial workers... As we do now.

Comment: All animals are equal. But some are more equal than others.

Answer (score 1):

#### Marx is purposely deceptive here

If we talk about classes of people, we have to define them. Formal definition would be that **classes are subsets of whole population with some common attributes**. You could make classes anyway you want (people who like or dislike professional sports, different classes by wealth, classes based on race or gender etc ..) In political philosophy, classes are usually defined as **groups of people with common political interest**. It is assumed that these classes could form political movements to represent them and push their ideas. Therefore Marx talked about political parties that represented working class, or high bourgeoisie, small land owners etc ... While in certain societies social mobility between classes was small to non-existent (it was almost impossible for serf to become noble for example), already in Marx's time this was not so anymore. There were the cases of people moving from rags to riches and vice versa .

What Marx purposely failed to mention, is that **in any society classes form naturally**. One example for that is supposedly classless USSR where class of party apparatchiks quickly rose to prominence once socialism took hold. Simply speaking, humans are different with different abilities, and nature abhors uniformity. Therefore, humans would always find the way to differentiate between themselves.

Why did Marx did that ? His final purpose was revolution of working class, and establishment of so called working class dictatorship ([Dictatorship of the proletariat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictatorship_of_the_proletariat)). Of course, in real life that dictatorship would actually be dictatorship of those who control socialist movement, and working class would remain where it is (at the bottom of society) . But selling idea of "classless" and "equality" to those under is always good proposition, because it promises rapid social rise from bottom to top.

Comment: Marx was a socialist. To him the difference between people is simply education. Sure there'll always be a class of people who are avaricious or seek power.. but eventually those people will be seen for what they are.

Comment: @Richard This doesn't matter, Marx was not stupid and he knew that people did have different cognitive abilities, and even when offered same education would not have same knowledge levels. He also knew that even socialist society would have hierarchy, therefore classes in it. Talk about classless society was just propaganda to incite lower classes of existing societies to rebel.

Comment: No. These are your beliefs.. not Marx's. No socialist believes people are born inferior. You might be right.. but I personally don't think so.

Comment: @Richard No, these are you current PC modern beliefs (rather ridiculous ) that have nothing to do with Marx. Marx never considered humans to be clones . I recommend reading this: https://www.marxists.org/archive/leontev/works/1978/ch1.htm , especially 1.3

Comment: sure.. this is why the Nazis loved Marx so much.. and Marx continues to inspire generations of neoconservatives and libertarians to this day.

Comment: @Richard My friend, with your "Nazi" rhetoric you really don't belong on philosophy SE . This is a place for people who think and read about the things they write, not for those who gulp cheap propaganda . As I said, if you want to know what Marx thought about certain things, read his works. If you plan to waste time with silly PC propaganda, I really don't have time for that.

Comment: I am slightly miffed that despite everything he said... You are attributing right wing opinions to Marx. Philosophy is about truth. What I did in my previous argument was to draw attention to the weakness of your argument by appealing to absurdity. This... Is how philosophers argue.

Comment: @Richard Marx would be probably considered "right wing" or at least "centrist" if he lived in our time. He was one of the founders of scientific materialism (also known as historical materialism) , and would certainly not pander to current perpetually offended by truth "leftists". In fact, by his criteria they would be considered as decadent liberal bourgeois ideology, with some idealistic positions (not a good thing from his perspective) .

Comment: @Richard Also, with all flaws and shortcomings of his theories, it was never his idea to force people to be "equal" . Instead, he simply claimed that socialist society (with means of production in the hand of working class, instead of capitalist) would allow better development of man in general (as a species ).

Comment: I'm sorry but you're just wrong. About everything. Believing that humans are born roughly mentally equal is not 'snowflake' stuff... It's just the truth.. but even if you appeal to authority here.. Marx was most certainly not on your side of the debate.. in any conceivable way. As I said earlier.. look up what he said about the inevitable emancipation of workers through education. Try looking for 'fifth stage'

Comment: @Richard If you really believe that, then you are sorrily under-educated. It is proven long ago that intelligence is mostly inherited. As I said before, Marx was never truth denier (unlike "leftist" today) , He wanted to emancipate workers by giving them opportunities to develop (in his socialist society), but never claimed that all of them would be uniformly equal (which is simply impossible in our world where even  twins are not completely equal).

Comment: @rs.29 I'm so glad you've told me this... My country has been wasting it's money on education systems for years... Just think of all the great stuff we'll be able to do now that money is freed up!